# error in mongodb mongoose used in nodejs express app:does not write to DB when using module.exports

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have successfully generated and launched a nodejs application with express generator.This part is OK. 
I have also created a standalone (single .js file)  prototype of mongoDB setup (using mongoose - first time for me). OK

They do the job well but I am stuck when I combine the 2. 
I assume my mistake is in the statements of module.exports but I can't figure out how to fix it.
Can anybody please help me to rewrite it?
nb I use "mongoose": "~5.3.16", (...if version is important ?)
My code (I skip some long parts):
/bin/www (for info, probably not the problem):

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('api-dfv2:server');
var http = require('http');
const loadConfig = require('../public/javascripts/loadConfig.js');
const config = loadConfig.getConfig();
var port = normalizePort(config.port);
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
function normalizePort(val) {(I skip...)
}
function onError(error) {(I skip here some code to handle errors+event listener for http server "listening" event...)
```

app.js :

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var loadConfig = require('./public/javascripts/loadConfig.js');

var Conversation = require('./src/conversation');//declared but never read probably something wrong there    

//the routers we need
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var dfv2Router = require('./routes/dfv2');

//initiate express with moment
var app = express();
//link with moment module
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');>>upgrade to pug
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//let's load the initial config (or defaults) 
//it will exit if no credentials are provided.
loadConfig.setConfig();

/**
 * map the routes
 */
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/dfv2', dfv2Router);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

in dfv2.js, I receive POST requests from a chat system and I want to store that content in mongoDB :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const conversation = require('../src/conversation')
/* POST received from chat system */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  dialogflowv2.getDFResponse(req.body)//I generate the answer to the chat
  .then((DFanswer) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(DFanswer));//not a nice way to debug but it works until that point
var currentConversation = new conversation;
console.log('test5');
currentConversation = {"moment": "test"};//I should write the full mapping with the body etc. here just to test one field
console.log(JSON.stringify(currentConversation));
   currentConversation.save() // THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG XXXXXX
   //.then(function(tmp) {console.log("ok : ",tmp)})
    //.catch(function() {console.log("DB error :")})
   res.status(200).json(DFanswer);

  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json(JSON.stringify(err.message)))
   })

 module.exports = router;
```

for info, conversation.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const server = '127.0.0.1:27017'; //  DB SERVER
const database = 'test_laurent';      //  DB NAME
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${server}/${database}`,{useNewUrlParser: true})
       .then(() => {
         console.log('Database connection successful - system ready')
       })
       .catch(err => {
         console.error('Database connection error')
       })
//get mongoose to use the global promise library
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
//to bind error of DB with console
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

let mySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    body: String,
    sessionId: String,
    moment: String      
})
let conversation = db.model('conversation', mySchema);
module.exports = conversation;
```

The result is that my DB doesnt receive anything. But it work well if I take all the code of conversation.js as standalone app (POST > generate schema > construct object > object.save > my collection is then created and visible in Compass so the DB and its connection is not the problem).
thank you in advance, any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conversion is a constructor but you are not calling that when creating a new conversation.

Do this:-

```
const currentConversation = new conversation({moment: test});
```

Also .save() returns a promise so you have to await it so append a .then.catch block to .save method

```
currentConversation.save()
     .then()
     .catch()
```

Comment: thank you so much ! It works. I was so focused on module.exports that I forgot to check my syntax  of the new conversation ... and parenthesis were missing (nb in my full code I had already a .then/.catch).